# Coding convention for adding rows to Pandas Dataframe in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conventions

I'm writing a program where I want to extract data from multiple docx files and fill it into a pandas dataframe. I'm currently achieving this in a for loop like so:

```
cols = ["path","col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]

def add_to_df(path):
    col1_val = extract_col1(path)
    col2_val = extract_col2(path)
    col3_val = extract_col3(path)
    col4_val = extract_col4(path)

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(
        [[path, col1_val,col2_val,col3_val,col4_val]],
        columns=cols) 
    return temp_df

df = pd.DataFrame() 
for path in paths:
    df = df.append(add_to_df(path), ignore_index=True)
```

Is this the best way to do this? Or is there a nicer, more accepted way? (This is just a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, the actual code looks a lot messier...)

Comment: pd concat is another option, which is fairly faster than append when used properly. have a read here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html. one suggestion : get all the data into a list before concatenating.

Answer (score 2):

I think better is create list of lists instead many `DataFrame`s and then pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
def add_to_df(path):
    col1_val = extract_col1(path)
    col2_val = extract_col2(path)
    col3_val = extract_col3(path)
    col4_val = extract_col4(path)

    temp_L = [path, col1_val,col2_val,col3_val,col4_val]
    return temp_L
```

List comprehension solution:

```
L = [add_to_df(path) for path in paths]
```

If want to use for loop:

```
L = []
for path in paths:
    L.append(add_to_df(path))
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer extracting data to a dictionary first and then create a dataframe from that dictionary. Example:

```
data = {'doc1': {'subject': 'x', 'n_words': 100},
        'doc2': {'subject': 'y', 'n_words': 200},
        'doc3': {'subject': 'z', 'n_words': 300}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

print(df)
```

Result:

```
     subject  n_words
doc1       x      100
doc2       y      200
doc3       z      300
```